# How can I be warned of a potential NameError?

Tags: python, nameerror

Here's an example of a Python script:

```
n, dollar, euro = map(input().split())
if n == 1:
   print(dolar / euro)  # Note the typo, 'dolar' vs. 'dollar'
else:
   print(euro / dollar)
```

I made a mistake ("dolar" with one 'l'). The interpreter won't inform of an `error(NameError)` or even a warning unless you enter `n = 1`.

How can I be informed of that at runtime?

Comment: Also, you are calling `map` incorrectly and unnecessarily: `n, dollar, euro = input.split()`

Comment: Downvoters: it's a legitimate question. Just because there is a corner case where `dolar` is intended and correct doesn't mean it isn't useful to have a tool to draw your attention to it.

Comment: What exactly do you expect this code do? What's the user input, and what you expect as the output?

Answer (score 7):

[pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857/) will report this as `E:  3: Undefined variable 'dolar'`, as well as giving you lots of useful style tips.

Python itself can't make things like this compile-time errors, since it can't really tell that you're not dynamically creating that name without running the code that leads to it. (Pylint will consider it an error even if you happen to do that, which is fine because if you write code like that you deserve to have it scored badly...)

Answer (score 3):

Use Pylint:

```
sucmac:~ ajung$ /tmp/bin/pylint ou.py 
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module ou
W:  3,0: Bad indentation. Found 3 spaces, expected 4
W:  5,0: Bad indentation. Found 3 spaces, expected 4
C:  1,0: Missing docstring
C:  1,0: Invalid name "n" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
C:  1,3: Invalid name "dollar" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
C:  1,11: Invalid name "euro" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
W:  1,18: Used builtin function 'map'
W:  1,22: Used builtin function 'input'
E:  3,9: Undefined variable 'dolar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python can't inform you ahead of run-time, because there are ways of inserting "dolar" into the symbol table before that line occurs, and Python can't detect whether you have done that until it actually attempts to run the line.  As Josh Lee put it, your best bet is to make a test-suite that (at the very least) exercises every line of your code.